# Error while reading ppm file in python using PIL

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, ppm

```
import os
import glob
from scipy.misc import imread
from PIL import Image

class NpyGenerator:

    def __init__(self, directory):
        if not os.path.isdir(directory):
            raise ValueError('The argument is not a valid directory')

        directory = os.path.join(directory, '')
        self.directory = directory

    def convert(self):
        # Here convert loop through all the files in the directory and convert it to NpyFile
        filelist = glob.glob(self.directory + '*_intensity.ppm')
        print("The number of files detected = ", len(filelist))
        for intensityFile in filelist:
            phaseFile = intensityFile.replace("_intensity", "_phase")
            inten_img = Image.open(intensityFile)
            phase_img = Image.open(phaseFile)



if __name__ == '__main__':

    directory_1 = 'D:/save/Rotifiers'
    npyGen = NpyGenerator(directory_1)
    npyGen.convert()
```

The error i get is:

Exception has occurred: ValueError
Too many colors for band: 65535

I want to know if there is a way to fix this error

Python Version: 3.7.

Answer (score 1):

One, or more, of your images is 16-bit and colour. PIL only supports greyscale 16-bit images.

Possible solutions:

- load images using OpenCV, or `wand`
- convert images to 8-bit per channel before opening using **ImageMagick**, Photoshop, GIMP or other tool.